# How to use javascript type="module" locally in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, server, module

I was working on a project with a local server.

In this project, i'm using modules, so my `index.html` contains:

```
    <script src="js/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

And my `index.js` contains:

```
    import {} from "/js/randomModule.js";
    import {} from "/js/randomModule.js";
    ...
```

All ran perfectly, but when I want to use the project directly on a browser, without a server, this was the problem:

```
Access to the script at 'file:///C:/Users/myFolder/js/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
index.html:54 

GET file:///C:/Users/myFolder/js/index.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

So, is there a way to use javascript `type="module"` directly in a brower without a server?

Comment: Consider using a simple server and not opening the file directly in the browser? If you're on unix/mac and have node installed I recommend `npx serve` https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve or [browsersync.io](https://www.browsersync.io/) for all platforms

Comment: or Install Live Preview Extension in your editor or browser

Answer (score 7):

As stated on [MDN docs about JS modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts):

> You need to pay attention to local testing — if you try to load the
> HTML file locally (i.e. with a file:// URL), you'll run into CORS
> errors due to JavaScript module security requirements. You need to do
> your testing through a server.

So sadly, no, you can't run JS with "type='module'" directly in the browser without server.

There are plenty options to run a local server: W/X/LAMP stack, oldschool `php -S localhost:8080`, node with express.js & static directory, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with `file://` protocol as stated in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts).